# What is $rootscope.$$phase = null?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use kendo ui and angular.js in my application. When i do some actions like hover or click event on some elements i see that other elements simply disappear.
I debug it and see in angular.js file

```
$rootscope.$$phase = null;
```

and then the elements disappear.

What is this:

```
$rootscope.$$phase = null;
```

and how to prevent it?

Comment: Checkout this link:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9980

Comment: @HanletEscaño: Nothing over there seems to answer this question. I am looking for an answer here, as well.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper oh this is old. I removed my comment. Good luck!